# How do I switch the Ubuntu Nexus 7 onscreen keyboard to show "()", "{}" characters?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, touchscreen, nexus-7

I managed to get the "(" and ")" characters displayed once in the onscreen keyboard but I don't know how I did it.  What is the secret to getting these special characters to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (above left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, at lower left of on-screen keyboard).

Then just press '{', '}', '(', or ')' as required.

---

This is close to the behavior for a normal ('tactile') keyboard, except that the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed **first**, instead of *at the same time*.